# Would it be legal to use this technology for my research project?

Tags: us3906934

In reference to the patent: [US3906934](https://www.google.com/patents/US3906934)

I would like to use this technology for a research project, is that legal?

Comment: Sep 23, 1975 was a very long time ago

Answer (score 1):

This patent expired a long time ago so you are free to practice the technology described within it. This doesn't mean there aren't newer patents you might need to be aware of. In either case, if you are only doing research and not applying the work commercially, I think you are Ok, but it would be nice for one of the actual patent attorneys or agents to verify that I'm correct. As was pointed out in the comments, you should cite the patent in any publications as you would any academic source.

Comment: You may want to provide attribution for the terminology if you copy it verbatim.  While the technology may be in the public domain, there could be copyright issues if the inventor published a description of the technology using the language in the patent.   Since it is for research, you would have a claim for fair use, but it still would be best to provide attribution.

Comment: @PatentPendingGuide Your comment is worthwhile. I'm assuming that if the questioner is doing academic research he/she would follow acceptable norms for citing other's work. Since this site concerns only patents, I answered with that in mind.